# Can we always find such a permutation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number. Does there always exist integers $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_{p-1}\}$ which is a permutation of $\{1,2,3,...,p-1\}$ such that $a_1^{1}+a_2^{2}+\cdots+a_{p-1}^{p-1}$ is divisible by $p$?

Ideas so far:

I have tried taking a primitive root modulo p and ranging it and considering the sum of it with the other $p-2$ terms.
Another idea I had was to somehow find a permutation so that we got $1,2,...,p-1$ modulo $p$. Both of these have failed.

I do not even know if the answer to the problem statement is positive. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: An easier (and much more likely to be true) variant would be to show that there are infinitely many p such that it satisfies the problem statement (instead of  trying to show that it is true for all p).

Comment: This is an interesting question: After running a bf(until prime 1489) up to 1487 the first permutation(lexicographically) fixes all numbers up to p-8 for p>8. In the case of 1489, the first permutation only fixes the first 8 numbers. I tried bf using a permutation generated with a primitive element, it doesn't work for p=101 for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: This problem has been solved already by someone else a while ago. I am posting it since it appears that a few people are still visiting this thread and I hope to provide a complete solution. The proof is surprisingly quite elegant.
[Solution by u\ComfortableOwl2322 is as follows]**

Yes, you always can.

**Proof**: We think of the powers as being set by the permutation instead, i.e. 1^{a_{1}} + (p-1)^{a_{p-1}}

Fix a primitive root A. It suffices to show that there is a {a_1,...,a_{p-1}} such that the part of the sum for the odd powers of A is equal to the part of the sum for even powers of A --- i.e.

(A^1)^a_1 + (A^3)^a_3 + (A^5)^(a_5) + ... + (A^p-2)^{a_{p-2}) = (A^2)^a2 + .... + (A^{p-1})^a_{p-1} (mod p).

To see this, note that we can replace {a_1, ..., a_{p-1}} by the shift  of adding (p-1)/2 to each a_i (mod p-1). This has the effect of negating the left side above, but preserving the right side, so, if the left and right sides were originally equal, the sum would be zero after this shift.

But actually we can explicitly give a_1,..., a_{p-1} such that the above equation holds ---- even term for term! Namely, take a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 4, a_4 = 3, ..., a_{p-2} = p-1, a_{p-1} = p-2.

Note then that (A^{2i-1})^{a_{2i-1}} = (A^{2i-1}) ^{2i} = {A^{2i}} ^{2i-1} = {A^{2i}}^{a_{2i}}.

**Construction**: Unwinding the proof details, we have the following procedure to obtain a setting of the original powers which gives zero sum:

1. Choose a primitive root A mod p.
2. For each A^2i, i.e. even power of A, choose its power to be (2i-1+ (p-1)/2) mod (p-1).
3. For each A^{2i-1}, i.e. odd power of A, choose its power to be (2i + (p-1)/2) mod (p-1).

For example, take p=11. A primitive root is 2, with powers (2,4,8,5,10,9,7,3,6,1), and we take our exponents to be (2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9) shifted by (p-1)/2 = 5 mod 10, so (7,6,9,8,1,10,3,2,5,4).

And one can check that 2^7+4^6+8^9+...+1^4 = 0 (mod 11).

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't proved yet, it seems like this construction works

let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$ .
then atleast one of
$\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (g^i)^i$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (g^{i-1})^i$ is divisible by p.

Edit : proof :-

if $p \equiv 1(mod 4)$ .

We show that the second summation works

as $g^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1(mod p)$

$g^k( mod p) $ depends on $k (mod p-1) $ .

We show that each i can be paired with j such that $j(j-1)=i(i-1)+\frac{p-1}{2}(mod p-1)$ So that the terms cancel out in the sum.

if $p-1$ is factorized as $2^{\alpha}k$ where k is odd. we set $i \equiv j(mod k)$ . And $j \equiv 2^{\alpha-1}+i(mod 2^{\alpha})$, u can easily verify that it works.

if $p \equiv 3(mod 4)$

The first sum works we show there exists j such that

$j^2=i^2+\frac{p-1}{2}(mod p-1)$

If $p-1=2k$ where k is odd. set $j \equiv i(mod k)$ , and $j=i+1(mod 2)$ and use CRT .

I have not really shown why pairing is unique for each but hopefully, you can complete that part yourself.

Comment: I will put a proof if I get it

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It turns out it's easier to switch perspectives and fix the bases instead of the exponents. You may refer to the solution above if you're interested in seeing the solution.

Comment: I see but i think i proved it so i will just put it in